# Webpack exclude large library from some bundles

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5

In my project I need to bundle code from different files to different bundles (I'm creating chrome extension). But webpack loads a very large library that really uses only one bundle into all bundles. So I was trying to exclude this lib:

`webpack.config.js`

```
entry: {
      shared: ["@somelib"],
      popup: {
        import: "./src/index.tsx",
        dependOn: "shared",
      },
      background: {
        import: "./src/background/background.js",
        dependOn: "shared",
      },
      contentScripts: {
        import: "./src/content-scripts/content-scripts.js",
        dependOn: "shared",
      },
      injectedScript: {
        import: "./src/content-scripts/inject/injected-script.js",
        dependOn: "shared",
      }
}
```

In this case scripts that DO NOT use that lib do not work. The only bundle that uses shared lib works.
When I comment `dependOn` line script starts working. So I really need to exclude that unused lib from some scripts to optimize my build. How can I do it? Why even webpack includes unused code into the bundle? And why files that don't use that lib don't work without that lib? They just loads into the browser **without any errors** and don't do anything